# How to share website links in wechat

Tags: php, web, wechat

Hi I am try to add share link button of wechat in our website like these other one:

```
    <a class="skype social-icon" href="https://web.skype.com/share?url=http://example.com&text=I wanted you to see this site" target="_blank" title="Skype"><i class="fa fa-skype fa-lg"></i></a>
   <a class="sms social-icon" href="sms://&body=http://example.com" target="_blank" title="SMS"><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-lg"></i></a>
```

any one can help me to provide any example for share webpage on wechat

Answer (score -2):

I think right now the most important thing for doing a wechat moment-sharing is to make sure the website can be opened in the moment. As I know, most of the sites can't not opened in wechat moment. WeChat's browser ridiculously restrict the links from outside of the Wechat.